# ORM query with or statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to query users by list of id using in statement http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

It is possible to do it without string query and execute function?

I am looking for something like below

```
users = User.query.filter_by(id=[1,5,12,4])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `User.query.filter(User.id.in_([1, 5, 12, 4]))` ?